# expected "indent", got "outdent"

Tags: css, stylus

```
  ParseError: /Users/JMiller/Projects/multisport-momentum/public/stylesheets/style.styl:15

  11|     color #031634
  12| }
  13| a {
  14|     color font.color
> 15|     text-decoration none
  16| }
  17| 
  18| .header

  expected "indent", got "outdent"
```

What does this mean?  It has something to do with whitespace?  What whitespace?  How do I fix this?

Comment: Check the values of the whitespace before `color` and `text-decoration` -- perhaps one uses tabs and the other uses spaces. `xxd style.styl` is one useful tool; if you use `vim` or MacVim, you can also use `:set list` to see special characters formatted differently.

Comment: Both are tabs.  I have 'show whitespace' turned on in WebStorm.  No dice.  Any other suggestions?  I'm about to abandon this and try something like sass since this isn't productive for me.

Comment: What's `font.color`? I'm not sure, but I don't think `.` is allowed in variable names. That said, please stay with stylus, it's really quite nice. ;)

Comment: This definitely has to do with whitespace. I get the idea that the problem may not be line 15. Possible to share more of your .styl file?

Comment: @EricWendelin: not true, I get the same error with just the `a { ... }` from poster. Renaming `font.color` fixes it.

Comment: @LinusGThiel good call. I've never seen it "not" be whitespace until now, but then again I never tried non-alphanumeric variable names. Thanks for setting it straight :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here is error reporting more than anything else. Dots `.` are not allowed in stylus variable names (nor mixin names), so renaming `font.color` to e.g. `font-color` will solve your problem.

Comment: Just a side note: In the case that he was using hashes, which is a feature in stylus, this could actually be valid. If he was declaring it as a hash of course.

Answer (score 1):

Write property through the colon.
For Example:

```
fontFamily = {
   primary: unquote ("'Open Sans', sans-serif")
}

font-family: fontFamily.primary
```

WebStorm swears on this syntax. For this to change, add $ before the variable.
For Example:

```
$fontFamily = {
   primary: unquote ("'Open Sans', sans-serif")
}

font-family: $fontFamily.primary
```